# Pygame - everything seems to be working, but image does not load on

Tags: python, pygame, loading

I have been creating a simple game where you move a character around, but even though there are no error messages, my player's image does not load. Please help me take a look at my code.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

class player:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = 100
    self.y = 100
    self.image = pygame.image.load('Data/chracter.png')
    self.update(0)

  def update(self,pos):
    if pos != 0:
        self.x += pos
    display.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background_img = pygame.image.load('Data/background.jpg')
size = background_img.get_size()

pygame.mixer.init()                         
pygame.mixer.music.load('Data/song.wav')   
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.7)          
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)    

display = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption('Game')  

player1 = player()

while 1: 
  player1.update(0)

  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            player1.update(-10)
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            player1.update(10)

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            player1.update(0)
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            player1.update(0)           

  display.blit(background_img,(0,0))

  pygame.display.update()
  clock.tick(60)
```

I've just started using classes in pygame, so the errors might be there. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your indention is off. Try indenting those last 3 lines.

Comment: why do you think that image doen't load ? Maybe  you don't draw it or draw in wrong place.

Comment: Thanks for telling me of that mistake - I have changed it now. Furas, I think I had it drawn in the wrong place - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You draw player in wrong playce.

You have to do it after you draw background.

```
# clear buffer
display.blit(background_img,(0,0))

# draw all objects
#player1.draw(display)
display.blit(player1.image, (player1.x, player1.y))   

# send buffer to video card (and video card draw it on monitor)
pygame.display.update()
```

-

btw: suggestions:

- use CamelCase names for classes - `class Player`
- don't draw in `player.update()`
- create `player.draw(surface)` method
- use `pygame.Rect` to keep player/objects position and size, and use it to draw image, detect collisions.

.

```
# draw
blit(self.image, self.rect)

# check collision
self.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect)
```

And better organize code - put classes before `pygame.init()` - for example [simple template](https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/blob/master/pygame/__template__/1__simple__.py) and [other examples](https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/tree/master/pygame/__template__)

Answer (score 0):

Correct it so it looks like this:

```
def update(self,pos):
        if pos != 0:
            self.x += pos
        display.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))
        pygame.display.update()
```

Your fps is to large btw so change it to 27 like:

```
clock.tick(27)
```

But you don't need to.